# How to use ragel labels outside the scope of machine instantiation

Tags: ragel

When an action is executed I want the action to trigger a jump to another state under certain conditions.
For code readability I'd also like to define the action outside of the machine instantiation.

How can I access the state labels generated by ragel outside the scope of the machine instantiation?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int cs=1;

%%{
    machine simpleMachine;  
    write data;
}%%

//The code for ActionA and ActionB is defined outside the scope 
//of the instatiation for readability

void a(void)
{   //Called for ActionA
}

void b(void)
{   //Called for ActionB
    int var2=0;
    if (var2==0)
    {
        %%{
            fgoto STATE_A; 
            #This fgoto generates a ragel parse error
            #how to use the STATE_A label outside 
            #of the machine definition?
        }%%
    }
}
void ExecuteSM(const char *p)
{   const char *pe = p + strlen( p );
    int var1=0; 
    %%{
        EVENT1 = 'a';
        EVENT2 = 'b';
        EVENT3=  'c';

        action ActionA
        {   a();
            if (var1==0)
            {
                fgoto STATE_B; //This fgoto compiles OK
            }
        }
        action ActionB
        {
            b();//I'd like to execute an fgoto in the function b() but I get a 
               //parse error
        }
        myfsm := (
                #STATE          EVENT               ACTION              NEXT_STATE
            start:(             EVENT1              >ActionA            ->STATE_A), 
            STATE_A:(           EVENT2              >ActionB            ->STATE_B),
            STATE_B:(           EVENT3)             
        );
    write init nocs;
    write exec;
    }%%
}
int main()
{
    ExecuteSM("abc");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgoto` is only available in code blocks, i.e. between `{` and `}` in a Ragel FSM specification.

In your example, you have put the fgoto outside of a code block (the `%%{ }%%` just opens/closes a multi-line FSM specification).

If your objective is to put the action-code where your functions `a()`/`b()` currently are, you can just do that - as actions. This would improve code-readability at least as much as your current idea.

Your example thus modified:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int cs=0;

%%{
  machine simpleMachine;  
  write data;

  action ActionA
  {
    if (var1 == 0)
      fgoto STATE_B; //This fgoto compiles OK
  }
  action ActionB
  {
    int var2 = 0;
    if (var2 == 0)
      fgoto STATE_A; 
  }
}%%

void ExecuteSM(const char *p)
{
    const char *pe = p + strlen(p);
    int var1 = 0; 
    %%{
        EVENT1 = 'a';
        EVENT2 = 'b';
        EVENT3 = 'c';

        myfsm := (
            #STATE       EVENT       ACTION       NEXT_STATE
            start:  (    EVENT1      >ActionA     ->STATE_A), 
            STATE_A:(    EVENT2      >ActionB     ->STATE_B),
            STATE_B:(    EVENT3)             
        );
        write exec;
    }%%
}
int main()
{
    %% write init;
    ExecuteSM("abc");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I've also changed your `init nocs` statement. Custom initialization should only be necessary in very special circumstances - and then it is preferably to use symbolic state names.

I've left the `cs` declaration at translation unit level, although in that example declaring (and initializing) it locally in `ExecuteSM` would be more appropriate.

Comment: If I want to generate an event within an action (for example generate EVENT3 within ActionA) what is a good way to do this?  Currently I am doing this:   { fexec "a";pe=p+2;//Generate EVENT1}  Is this the recommended way of generating an event within an action?